# Is there a chance that I can find an outpost spot in reach of 2 different resources that, according to the scans, don't touch or overlap?

Tags: starfield

I am interested in the answer in general, but to be more specific I'm prospecting Eridani-VII-c for a base where I could mine Titanium and use nearby existing natural He-3 deposits to fuel an inter-system cargo link that would send the ores right back to my main base. The problem is I'm having trouble finding a spot where I can reach both resources, as you can see according to my rank 3 scan, there no place where the He-3 and Ti fields touch:

[image: Rank 3 scans of Eridani-VII-c]

Am I wasting my time looking for the perfect spot ?

Comment: One way would be to create a cargo link on the same planet (no need for Helium-3) and send the harvested resources to the other central collecting spot on the same planet. From there, you send all resources through a cargo inter-system link to the system/planet/target spot wherever you need it. On the screenshot above, I can't see any spot sufficient for your current idea.

Comment: I trying to not waste any outpost slots I'm worried that I won't have enough for all the major resources + He-3 once per system for transportation

Comment: You can level up your skill "Planetary Habitation" (Science skill tree). Once at master-tier rank 4, you will be able to build a total of 24 different outposts across the cosmos.

Comment: There is some value in finding exact spots right where two biomes intersect, which, depending on the planet and biome, can yield outposts that can 'connect' to more than the usual amount of resources that maybe are split across the biomes. But... how helpful that is depends on the planet, biomes, resources involved, etc. ‍♀️

Comment: There are 47 Resources and 32 Organic resources and I'm pretty sure there are quests that require you to build outposts even if its just temporarily, so I'm pretty sure that I will run out of slots if I don't optimize my bases

Comment: I had some success in building outposts at the edge of 2 biomes getting resources from multiple sectors, I'm just not sure what is possible what not, there is a method to the madness of the world tile generator, there is just so much I don't understand about this game

Comment: I have an untested idea on how to reduce the number of base:
Next time if I have to build an inter-system He-3 Relay base, instead of doing the minimum, I will try to go all out, build an industrial He-3 mining complex that will supply multiple bases in multiple system with He-3 , if I run out of connections maybe I could just set up a chain where each base sends the next some He-3 and the produce.  This might just work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR General answer: Yes.**

For a general answer, I remembered I had an outpost like this already on Andraphon.

From this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIvxC.jpg), you can clearly see, there is no Aluminum nearby my outpost. I actually selected a gray spot in between the Iron and Helium-3 to try and get both of those resources, and was pleased to find Aluminum as well in this landing zone. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l3KW.jpg), that I can place down an extractor for all 3 (Aluminum, Helium-3, and Iron) at this outpost. Interestingly, the Aluminum and Helium-3 deposits were much larger than this small Iron deposit.

**TLDR Eridani-VII-C: Yes.**

I was able to find a [spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxJ4c.jpg) that had both [Helium-3 and Titanium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA81G.jpg) on Eridani-VII-C. The size of the two ([Helium-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFap0.jpg), [Titanium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zG8Q.jpg)) deposits were a bit on the small side, but with some more time, I could have probably found a better spot (this spot also has Lead and Aluminum however).

I don't know if that exact spot will be the same for you or not. I know POI's are procedurally generated, but I'm not sure if resource maps and landing zones are or not. However finding a similar spot to mine shouldn't be too difficult.

The trick is finding which biomes each resource spawns in. In this example, Titanium spawns in rocky deserts, and Helium-3 spawns in craters. This holds true, even if the resource map doesn't necessarily show any resource at that location. Once you know which biome each spawns in, zoom all the way in and select a spot and keep moving around until you can find a border between the two biomes. This can be a little tricky, but if you select a landing zone and it shows rocky desert, then you move the landing zone only slightly and it shows craters, you should be able to find a border at one of those landing zones.

Once you have selected a landing zone at the border of the two biomes you need, you will need to run around the landing zone to find the border there. In this instance, craters are more flat areas and have a gray soil, whereas rocky deserts tend to be more mountainous and have a yellowish soil. I found it easier to land in a craters area and run towards the nearest mountains until I found a sudden change in soil color.

After finding the biome border at your landing zone, simply run along the border with an outpost out to be placed and watch the top left of the screen until you find one of the resources you are looking for, then move it around to see if the other is also in range. If it isn't simply continue running along the border and repeat the process until you find an appropriate spot. It may take a bit of time, but you should be able to replicate this on any planet, and I have done it a few times now on different planets with the same result, though search times have varied.

Comment: The map you see from orbit are the _primary_ deposits in a given location, not the only deposits. I have a colony on Ixyll-II solidly in the center of a biome with 6 different resources. No need to do biome border running on planets with abundant resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Finding the border between biomes was harder than expected, local map helped somewhat also it seems like a biome change not necessary means that the resources change.